# Property Set of same Class throws Exception StackOverflow in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, oop, set, stack-overflow, data-class

The problem goes away when instead of **data class** I use simply a **class** or instead of a **MutableSet** I use an **ArrayList**. I am trying to understand what is wrong in the way I first wrote it and can't find anything wrong, but it throws a StackOverflow error when running the last line

```
data class Person(
    val id : Int,
    val neighbors : MutableSet<Person> = mutableSetOf()
)

fun main() {

    val neighbor1 = Person(0)
    val commonNeighbor = Person(1)
    val neighbor2 = Person(2)
   
    commonNeighbor.neighbors.addAll(listOf(neighbor1,neighbor2))
    neighbor1.neighbors.add(commonNeighbor)
    neighbor2.neighbors.add(commonNeighbor)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming you are using Kotlin/JVM)

The stack trace makes this a lot clearer. Notice that the stack trace is a repetition of calling these two methods.

```
at bar.Person.hashCode
at java.base/java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode
```

Let's consider what happens when you add `commonNeighbor` into `neighbour2.neighbours` in the final line.

`mutableSetOf` creates a linked hash set, and in order to be added to a hash set, `commonNeighbour` needs to be hashed.

An implementation of `hashCode` is automatically generated for `Person` because it is a data class, and this is what is used to hash it. This implementation takes into account (i.e. also calls `hashCode` on) the properties declared in `Person`'s primary constructor, which are `id` and `neighbours`.

So to hash `commonNeighbours`, we need to hash `commonNeighbours.id` and `commonNeighbours.neighbours`. What neighbours do `commonHeighbours` have? `neighbour1` and `neighbour2`. In order to hash *them*, we need to hash *their neighbours* too. But wait! One of `neighbour1`'s neighbours is `commonNeighbours`! We have gone back to where we have started, creating an infinite loop.

All of this wouldn't happen, if the `hashCode` of `Person` didn't consider `neighbours` (which is what making `Person` a non-`data` class would do), or if you weren't using a `HashSet`.